# Why HttpContext.Current dose not work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i store some information in my website (mvc3-.net4-iis7) by this syntax:

```
HttpContext.Current.Application.Add(appKey, value);
```

and read data by this one:

```
 HttpContext.Current.Application[appKey];
```

it works fine but after a short time (about 20 minutes) it works not and can not find [appKey],i want to know
has it some setting to do or has it expire time?

i change my cookie expire time to 7 days in my web.config but not working yet.

thanks for your helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those values are stored in-memory. If the application gets recycled by IIS, the AppDomain goes down and everything you have stored in memory is lost. Don't forget that IIS could recycle your application at any moment. For example if certain memory/CPU thresholds are met. So if you attempt to read the value without setting it after the application has been recycled it won't be there.

So you should consider using a more persistent place to store this information rather than storing it in-memory.

> i change my cookie expire time to 7 days in my web.config but not working yet.

Values that you store in the application state have nothing to do with cookies. They are stored on the server.

Comment: i put machine key in my config file,i want to know this can isolate my website to Private from  IIS could recycle?

Comment: You could configure IIS to never recycle the website even if you start running out of memory. Obviously this is a very bad idea and you should instead consider persisting this information in a more permanent location such as a file or a database.

Comment: what is your solution to me ?i want store members log in information until they are in their profile,after exiting remove these information

Answer (score 0):

This isn't to do with your cookie, HttpContext.Current is determined by your session, where the default is 20 minutes.

You can increase the time by setting in your web.config:

```
<configuration>
… some config here …
<system.web>
  <sessionState timeout="XXX" />
…some more config
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

It's worth noting, as Darin has, whether your approach is actually what you should be doing anyway.